# Resource files (css & js) not loading in safari

Tags: javascript, css, safari

The content (text & images) are loading but not the css & js files, and only in certain Safari on iMac, iPhone or other apple devices. 
Weird thing is it works in the Safari on my macbook pro, with the same internet connection.

The console displays the message "Failed to load resource: the network connection was lost" for every css and js files. Same if you try to access the file directly...

Here is the website: [twennys.com](http://twennys.com)

Comment: Aaaah Safari, the new Internet Explorer...

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the iPhone.

Tap Settings > Safari then swipe down and tap Clear History & Website Data then restart your iPhone then try your website.